# JQuery/Ajax - Como manter a página atualizada?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho uma página que é carregada com $.ajax() do JQuery, o ajax puxa uma página em php com um banco de dados que é atualizado constantemente e preciso manter a página atualizada, como séria o melhor jeito ?

Li sobre usar um `setTimeOut( '', 2000 );` mas achei que pesaria tanto q seria inviável, e li também sobre um timeout no próprio ajax da jquery mas não funcionou, atualizei o banco de dados e a página continuou igual, usei esse exemplo no script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    site();
});

function site() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "site.php",
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        timeout: 3000
    });
}
```

Adicionei o timeout dessa forma e nada mudou!

Answer (score 2):

O parâmetro de [configuração `timeout`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) é o intervalo de tempo que o ajax deve esperar pela resposta do AJAX, ou seja "tempo de caducidade" (não estou certo da palavra exata em potuguês).

O que queres é um ajax que se repete de *N* em *N* segundos, certo?

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
$(document).ready(site);

function site() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "site.php",
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function(){
            setTimeout(site, 3000);
        }
    });
}
```

Usei o `complete` pois é chamado sempre, caso seja sucedido ou não.

Comment: Oi Sergio, essa é a melhor forma ? não ficaria muito pesado o site ?

Comment: Essa é uma forma. De 3 em 3 segundos atualiza. Se fores buscar muito conteúdo é pesado. Mas nesse caso a técnica não é o problema mas sim a quantidade de dados que vais buscar sem filtrar o que é preciso ou não. Podes usar sockets e ter uma ligação constante, mas se não é necessário esta solução parece-me bem :) Podes usar React para gerir o que é inserido no DOM ou não, mas se é coisa simples assim deve chegar.

Comment: O websockets tende a ser mais econômico, pois o servidor informa o cliente quando houve mudança, ao invés do cliente ficar repetidas vezes perguntando se algo mudou. Porém a implementação disto nao é tão simples.