# Receber resposta Jquery e PHP de segundo em segundo

Tags: php, jquery

Galera,

Tenho uma pagina em PHP que faz uma consulta no banco de dados ao final do processamento eu mostro a quantidade de registros atualizados.
Esse processo demora um pouco, no meu Jquery eu só mostro o total de registros afetados, como poderia mudar meu Jquery para mostrar de tempo em tempo, no caso de a cada 1 segundo ele mostra para o usuário a quantidade de registros.

**EDIT:** **ATENÇÃO**
Eu não posso ficar chamando a pagina PHP várias vezes, preciso chamar uma unica vez e ficar escutando ela ou seja recebendo dados dela!

```
var form_data = new FormData();

         form_data.append('id', idSel);
         $.ajax({
             url: 'postar_reenvio.php', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
             type: 'POST',
             data: form_data,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             beforeSend: function () {
                $('.resp').html("<img src='images/spin.gif' alt='Notificação' height='70' width='70'/> <br>Enviando Mensagens, aguarde!");
            },
             success: function(response) {
```

Comment: Cria uma função que faz esse controle. E no `success` utilize o `setTimeout` para definir o tempo para chamar essa função novamente

Comment: Na minha pagina PHP eu só utilizo echo($cont);    Queria colocar um echo dentro do Loop que tenho na pagina PHP e cada 1 segundo e responder para o Jquery

Comment: Possível duplicata de [JQuery/Ajax - Como manter a página atualizada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145464/jquery-ajax-como-manter-a-p%c3%a1gina-atualizada)

Comment: @abfurlan Não é igual pq a questão que vc postou ele fica chamando a função "site" eu não quero chamar a função novamente, eu quero ficar recebendo os dados da pagina PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que para o propósito que vc quer, um Websocket é bem melhor do que requisições ajax de 1 em 1 segundo. Com websocket voce veria em tempo real.

Voce faria seu próprio script que está executando as querys enviar a informação pelo canal do socket.

Em php você pode utilizar estes exemplos:

http://socketo.me/

http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html

Answer (score 0):

Creio que no própria função

> beforeSend();

Você pode criar um loop informando a quantidade de registros inseridos. (Se é que eu entendi dessa forma).

Comment: Ao clicar no botão eu quero ficar recebendo os dados do PHP com o echo($cont); O BeforeSend serve no caso da imagem de carregamento que utilizei no exemplo.

Comment: Show, questão resolvida então?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `window.setInterval` do JS para chamar a função passando como parametro a função que deseja chamar e o tempo em milisegundos.

O Código ficaria assim:

```
var intervalo = window.setInterval(consulta, 1000);
function consulta() {
   var form_data = new FormData();
     form_data.append('id', idSel);
     $.ajax({
         url: 'postar_reenvio.php', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
         type: 'POST',
         data: form_data,
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         beforeSend: function () {
            $('.resp').html("<img src='images/spin.gif' alt='Notificação' height='70' width='70'/> <br>Enviando Mensagens, aguarde!");
        },
         success: function(response) {
        }
   }
```

E se desejar interromper o script use `clearInterval(intervalo);`.

Comment: No caso minha chamada está no click do botão   $('#submitButton').click(function() {

Comment: Vou precisar criar uma Function e depois chamar no botão? Outra coisa ele não vai ficar chamando minha pagina php varias vezes?

Comment: Pera ai, deixa eu ver se entendi. Você quer atualizar em tempo real os valores do cont do PHP que é retornada do AJAX?

Comment: Eu quero chamar a pagina PHP ok, em seguida dentro do PHP eu tenho um Loop e dentro desse Loop eu tenho um echo("total de registros") a cada passada no loop eu quero mandar a quantidade de registros atualizados.

Comment: Não sei se isso é possivel dessa maneira, porque o PHP vai processar todo o looping e vai retornar todos os echos de uma vez só para seu AJAX. Você pode tentar usar uma variavel de sessão armarzenando o valor de cont, e um setInterval printando sua variavel de sessão, ou talvez, uma variavel de servidor do php

Comment: Então estou pesquisando a respeito e não achei nada ainda é como se fosse uma Thread escutando, mas só posso chamar a pagina php uma unica vez e ficar escutando ela me mandando os registros afetados.